# Why am I missing nodes in my geometry nodes editor?

Tags: mesh, node-editor, geometry-nodes, versions

I'm currently following along with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QA13LPCZ3dM), and at 1:20 and 2:00, I noticed that in the add menu, I simply don't have the nodes "integer" or "dual mesh". They just don't exist, this has sparked quite a lot of confusion, and upon a google search, there was nothing I could find. Could use some help. cheers.

Comment: Check the Blender version in the tutorial and your version. GN is still developing and some nodes might exist only in newer version. If you want to follow that specific tutorial, download the same version what is used in the tutorial.

Comment: The `Dual Mesh` node has only been available since version 3.1. Perhaps you are still using an older version?

Answer (score 1):

*Just to be able to close the question:*

The `Dual Mesh` node was only introduced with the release of **Blender 3.1**.

Unfortunately, in video tutorials it is often not clear which version it is, and there are sometimes big differences between the versions.

[image]